# MVC - Post Route Not Working in IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-routing

I have an MVC project that works fine when in VS.
But when I publish it and use it in IIS, a search page always gives this result:

> No web page was found for the web address:

My controller has these two options:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[controller]")]
public IActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
```

&

```
public IActionResult Index(SearchModel model = null)
```

The page will load normally but once I perform the search in IIS it just wont work, any idea why this would be when VS handles it just fine.

Comment: What URL are you trying to access? Is there a controller-level Route attribute?

Comment: http://siteaddress/Search

I can hit the search page but once the post search is done its just 404. I have now changed it so the Index now performs the search if the model is not null and this also works in VS but now in IIS the /Search address gives 404 even in a get request???

I have no idea why this page wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Just incase this incredibly rare issue occurs for someone else!
I have finally managed to correct the fault by slowly removing code from the error page until it finally loaded.

The problem was making a call to a method in a class that made use of HtmlAgilityPack and Fizzler.
For some reason MVC cannot handle it, and not a single error of relevance was offered anywhere!!

I uninstalled both and found an MVC specific version in nuget packages.. Lord!